# Возможно ли упростить регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Вот сам regex:

```
[а-я]{1,30}|[a-z]{1,30}
```

Возможно ли избежать повторения `{1,30}`?

Comment: @NMD результат разный будет. указанное автором выражение ищет только русские либо только латиницу. если объединить, то будет вперемешку.

Comment: @teran, понял, точно

Comment: @NMD не подходит потому что я хочу чтоб в слове были или латинские буквы или кириллица

Answer (score -1):

вот код для тестов, как это все работает:

```
import re
def test_re(s):
    t = r'[а-я]{1,30}|[a-z]{1,30}'
    res = re.search(t, s)
    return res

testlist = [
            '',
            'кириллицаффффффффффффффффффффяяsss',
            'кириллицаsssssssssssssssssssssssss',
            'asciiaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzффф',
            'asciiффффффффффффффффффффффффффффф'
           ]
for x in testlist:
    print(test_re(x))
```

re.search(pattern, string)
Метод search() ищет по всей строке, но возвращает только первое найденное совпадение. Информация взята [тут](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/).

для t = r'([а-я]|[a-z]){1,30}' - перестает фильтровать кириллицу|латиницу.
По сути операция | (или) делит шаблон на две подстроки, поэтому дальнейшую обработку нужно применять к каждой подстроке.

Но! Можно так:

```
import re
def test_re(s):
    t = r'([а-я]+|[a-z]+)'
    res = re.search(t, s)
    return res.group(0)[:30:]
testlist = [
            'кириллицаффффффффффффффффффффяяsss',
            'кириллицаsssssssssssssssssssssssss',
            'asciiaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzффф',
            'asciiффффффффффффффффффффффффффффф'
           ]
for x in testlist:
    print(test_re(x))
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не отвечает на заданный вопрос, поэтому вас минусуют

Comment: может все таки отвечает... практически и теоретически?

Comment: Вам виднее, но фамильярность и неаккуратность тут не любят. Я не минусую, понимаю, что вы стараетесь как можете, но другие не оценят )

Comment: А я не понял.. Объясните пожалуйста где и в чем "фамильярность"?

Comment: Ну, я не совсем чётко выразился, не могу подобрать правильный термин. Но я бы вот это вырезал/поменял: "Так что "низя" сократить. Вот."

Comment: Удалил "фамильярность". Извините если что не так. )